# IEEE 802.11:deauthicated due to local deauth request Respberry pi 2 jessie

Tags: wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, hostapd

I am trying to make hotspot using Raspberry Pi 2. I have followed a video tutorial in which I have completed all steps successfully. I use TL-WN722N router.

Actually I'm facing an issue is that when connecting to the devices on other side. My Raspberry Pi Terminal throws an error:

> wlan0: STA *my_MACAddress* IEEE 802.11:deauthicated due to local deauth request